# Compare Delphi TFDQuery before and after Updates by fieldvalue

Tags: delphi, firedac

In my wrapper class around a TFDquery, there is a function called Update. That funciton is called by giving Fieldnames and Fieldvalue as VariantArray.

So inside that function the fields given within that fieldArray, will be filled with the value given within the valueArray.

looks like that:

```
procedure TWrapperClass.Update(fields, values: Variant);
var
  i: integer;
begin
...
  for i := VarArrayLowBound(fields, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(fields, 1) do
    DataQuery.FieldByName(UpperCase(vartostr(fields[i]))).Value := values[i];

  if DataQuery.UpdateStatus = usModified then
  begin
    DataQuery.FieldByName('UPDATEUSER').AsString := FUsername;
    DataQuery.FieldByName('UPDATETIMESTAMP').AsDateTime := now();
  end;
  DataQuery.Post;
end;
```

It is not Possible for me to know, if the Value I write into the Field is other than the existing one or if it realy changed the value.

I only want to write Updateuser and Updatetimestamp to DB if there was a real change. UpdateStatus does not work on that place. I would like to prevent checking every value against the new one for better performance. Is there a way to check the Query in state "before changing Values" with the Query in state "after changing Values" but before the Post?

Comment: I think you’ll need to check the existing value before setting it. When it’s different, set the record in edit mode. And a the end, when the record is in edit mode, post the record.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to check the Query in state "before changing Values" with the Query in state "after changing Values" but before the Post?

Well, the BeforePost event is called immediately before a TDataSet posts its current record.  I don't think you can achieve what you want, if I understand it correctly, without examining each field of interest.  You can find out how many fields have been changed by
making use of TField's `OldValue` property - see the documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TField.OldValue).
As you can see, the `OldValue` is only defined if the dataset is using `CachedUpdates`.

Here is a working example which creates an FDMemTable, inserts a single record in it and then persists if to disk, then reloads it and makes some changes to the record
and determines the number of changed fields - relative to the version which was read from disk.

It also shows a method of determining the count of prospective field changes if an array of values
were to be applied to the record, again compared to the version was read from the disk.

Code

```
uses
  ]...]

  FireDAC.Stan.StorageBin;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    FDStanStorageBinLink1: TFDStanStorageBinLink;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Log(S: String);
  public
  end;

[...]

function GetChangedFieldCount(MemTable : TFDMemTable) : Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to MemTable.FieldCount - 1 do
    if MemTable.Fields[i].OldValue <>  MemTable.Fields[i].Value then
      Inc(Result);
end;


function getProspectiveFieldChangeCount(MemTable : TFDMemTable; NewValues : variant) : Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
  V : Variant;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to MemTable.FieldCount - 1 do begin
    V := NewValues[i];
    if MemTable.Fields[i].Value <>  V then
      Inc(Result);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(S : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
  i : Integer;
  AFileName : String;
  S : String;
  NewValues : Variant;
begin
  //    First, create some TFields for FDMemTable1
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ID';
  AField.DataSet := FDMemTable1;

  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'Number1';
  AField.DataSet := FDMemTable1;

  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'Number2';
  AField.DataSet := FDMemTable1;

  FDMemTable1.CachedUpdates := True;

  //  Create dataset, insert a record and persist the table to disk
  FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;
  FDMemTable1.InsertRecord([1, 1, 1]);
  FDMemTable1.ApplyUpdates(0);

  AFileName := 'C:\temp\Atest.Fds';
  FDMemTable1.SaveToFile(AFileName);

  //  Close FDMemTable and reload it
  FDMemTable1.Close;
  FDMemTable1.LoadFromFile(AFileName);

  Memo1.Clear;

  S := Format('ChangedFieldCount: %d', [GetChangedFieldCount(FDMemTable1)]);
  Log(S);

  //  Make some changes and log them
  FDMemTable1.Edit;
  FDMemTable1.FieldByName('Number1').AsInteger := 100;
  FDMemTable1.Post;

  S := Format('ChangedFieldCount: %d', [GetChangedFieldCount(FDMemTable1)]);
  Log(S);

  FDMemTable1.Edit;
  FDMemTable1.FieldByName('Number2').AsInteger := 101;
  FDMemTable1.Post;

  S := Format('ChangedFieldCount: %d', [GetChangedFieldCount(FDMemTable1)]);
  Log(S);

  FDMemTable1.ApplyUpdates(0);

  //  Persist and reload the table
  AFileName := 'C:\temp\Atest.Fds';
  FDMemTable1.SaveToFile(AFileName);
  FDMemTable1.Close;
  FDMemTable1.LoadFromFile(AFileName);

  //  At this point the single record's contents should be
  //  [1, 100, 101]

  NewValues := VarArrayOf([1, 1, -1]);  //  That is, there are two changes in NewValues

  S := Format('ProspectiveFieldChangeCount: %d', [GetProspectiveFieldChangeCount(FDMemTable1, NewValues)]);
  Log(S);

end;

end.
```

Obviously, the two Count functions, as written, consider all the fields in the dataset.  If you are only interested in some of the fields, you would need to adjust their code to take account of that.

Comment: Hi MarynA,
in my opinon, checking oldvalue against value is the same amount of work like using DataQuery.FieldByName(UpperCase(vartostr(fields[i]))).Value = values[i] to compare if something is different. After some sleep there are some more thoughts :). In moste cases not all Fields of a Row are changed, most time only 20% - 30% are changed. Under performance consideration, it would be faster to check if there are new values, than writting every field. Am I right?